# name vs. name.default when creating a library with webpack

Tags: webpack

Is there a way to pack a library so I can refer to its entry point as simply `foo` and not `foo.default`?

I create a library with the following code:

structure:

```
.
|-- src
|   |-- index.js
|-- webpack.config.js
|-- dist
|   `-- index.html
|-- package.json
```

./src/index.js

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
var dk = function dk(selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
};

Object.assign(dk, {
    __version__: 42,

    ready(fn) {
        jQuery(fn);
    }
});

export default dk;
```

./webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',    
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'dk.js',
        library: 'dk',
        libraryTarget: "var"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        presets: ['env'],
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery',
    }
};
```

./dist/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hello world</h1>

    <script src="dk.js"></script>
    <script>
        var dk = dk.default;  // <=== HERE: why do I need this line?

        dk.ready(function () {
            dk('h1').innerText = 'so long and thanks for all the fish';
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I believe I've done everything according to the documentation, but I didn't expect the `.default` indirection. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do dk.default because of the way that was created.

DK is an es module so it has a default export and named exports. Different from common.js you need to import as default.

When you require an es module, you get access to an object: `{_esmodule: true|false, default: ....}` which describes your module.

This has nothing to do with webpack, you just have to pack your module as commonjs, not as esmodule.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean to change `libraryTarget` to `"commonjs-module"`?  I've tried that, and then I get `ReferenceError: module is not defined` and `ReferenceError: dk is not defined`

Comment: no i did not ment that, i meant how your module is created.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. How do I create my module to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: put on google how to create es module and commonjs module.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty new to both webpack and modules, but after some deep googling I found the solution..  All of the following are required in the output section:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'dk.js',
    library: 'dk',
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    libraryExport: 'default',
    umdNamedDefine: true
},
```

it's related to this bug report https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3929 and the solution is based on code from this PR https://github.com/dharmaprotocol/dharma.js/pull/145.

**Update:** in case anyone else is as clueless as me, the original output section can be used if the last line in `index.js` is changed from

```
export default dk;
```

to

```
module.exports = dk;
```